# How are parental monitoring apps able to see social media messages?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I was creating a parental monitoring app and I was able to include the geotracking, screen recording, and other features for a school project. How to get social media messages like WhatsApp, Telegram, Instagram, etc. like other parental monitoring apps? I am developing using Kotlin.

I've looked for libraries that can accomplish the task but failed to do so.

Comment: I don't think that's possible/legal

Comment: You'd need to see if those apps provide an API to get them, either locally or remotely via web requests.  There's no way to get at the files of another app (they're all private to that app), so no way to get those from the app unless they actively provide an API (and I would be truly shocked if any of them did, it would be a HUGE privacy violation and probably be against the GDPR in EU for them to)

Comment: For Facebook it looks like the messages may be available via the Graph API, if the user connects your app to FB via OAuth.  But you won't be able to get most of them, and it's going to be a one off implementation for each program you want to work with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.